# Use of abbreviations in travel descriptions

Tags: abbreviations, connotations

How would you construct the following sentence? I wanted to express that these cards are rarely accepted and typically at shops and services for tourists. Is it clear? If it is not how would you rephrase it?

"Amex and diners are accepted rarely, especially at taxi, hotels or frequent tourist places."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity, I would write them out and phrase the sentence a little differently. For instance, you could say,

> "American Express and Diners Club International cards are rarely accepted, especially by taxis, hotels and other places frequented by tourists."

Comment: So the usage of "especially" is OK. I was not sure whether it does not imply a negation in fact.

Comment: Yes, you used it correctly. To imply a negation you would use "except" instead of "especially"; for instance, "American Express and Diners Club International cards are rarely accepted, except by major international hotel chains." (I don't know if this is a true statement - it is just an example of how you might use "except.") Thank you for accepting my answer.